# Calculate difference between two times in range of columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to calculate the difference between every row `A5` to `A20` and `B5` to `B20` and change the color to green if it equals 4 hours. I'm having a hard time setting up a range. I currently can only do one cell at a time.

```
Sub test()
    Dim Total As Double
    Dim Timein As Date
    Dim Timeout As Date
    Timein = CDate(Range("A7").Value)
    Timeout = CDate(Range("B7").Value)

    Total = 24 * ((Timeout - Timein))
    Debug.Print Total
    Debug.Print Format(Total, "#,##0_);(#,##0)")
    If Total = 4 Then
        Range("A7").Interior.Color = vbGreen
    End If

    Debug.Print "Number of hours = " & Total * 24
End Sub
```

[image: Photo Example Here]

Comment: does it have to be vba? why not a formula? or conditional formatting? if you 100% need vba, look into `for each ... next` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you even using VBA for this task?  Excel has built-in commands and functionality (conditional formatting) just for things like that.  Using VBA is an overkill.

```
Sub test()

    Dim dteIn As Date
    Dim dteOut As Date
    Dim rng As Range, cll As Range

    Set rng = Range("A5:A20")

    For Each cll In rng
        dteIn = CDate(cll.Value)
        dteOut = CDate(cll.Offset(0, 1).Value)
        If CInt((dteOut - dteIn) * 24) = 4 Then
            cll.Interior.Color = vbGreen
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I believe the formatting may be incorrect. Does not seem to be working.

Comment: Slight change, try it now

Comment: Perfect Thank you!!